# Boolean algebras without the least element

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic

I read somewhere that A.Tarski introduced Boolean algebras without the least element, but could not find a free article about them. If anybody knows the axioms of such an algebra, can you please share?

Comment: Do you mean the $0$? How do you have an algebra without a $0$?

Comment: The generalized boolean algebras without the greatest element (usually denoted as "1") are better known. The boolean algebras without a "0" are less known, but there are such algebras. They were invented to model the proper-part relationship in a mereology where "empty part" is not accepted.

Comment: You can see [Mereology](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mereology/), specifically Section 4, and the biblio refernces to the works of Tarski and Mostowski.